# How to efficiently remove the same-length elements from a list in python

Tags: python

For example, I have a list:

`[[1,3],[23,4],[13,45,6],[8,3],[44,33,12]]`

Is there any efficient way that I can finally get the list below?

`[[1,3],[13,45,6]]`

For every length of the list, keep only one element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make a dictionary keyed off the length and get its values:

```
>>> l = [[1,3],[23,4],[13,45,6],[8,3],[44,33,12]]
>>> dict((len(i), i) for i in l).values()
[[8, 3], [44, 33, 12]]
```

Comment: Nice, just use the reversed list!

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure if it mattered which one was chosen, and throwing reversed in made it look too ugly for a one-liner :-)

Comment: it doesn't matter which one was chosen. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Ben Why so? Its just `{len(i):i for i in l[::-1]}.values()`

Comment: Good point. I forgot about using a negative slice step and a dict comprehension (stuck with Py 2.6 for work)

Answer (score 1):

`s = set()
[e for e in l if len(e) not in s and s.add(len(e)) is None]`

Answer (score 0):

And then there is always explicit recursion ...

```
>>> l = [[1,3],[23,4],[13,45,6],[8,3],[44,33,12]]
>>> def f(x):
...     if x == []: return []
...     else      : return [x[0]] + f( filter(lambda m:len(m)!=len(x[0]),x) )
... 
>>> f(l)
[[1, 3], [13, 45, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

map the list to set of element lengths and pull out elements with coresponding length, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/py3
#coding: utf-8

def uniqlens (ls):
  for length in set(map(lambda x: len(x), ls)):
    for elem in ls:
      if len(elem) == length:
        yield elem
        break

coll  = [[1,3],[23,4],[13,45,6],[8,3],[44,33,12]]
print(list(uniqlens(coll)))
# [[1, 3], [13, 45, 6]]
```